# Two-player Mancala

Tags: c++, beginner, game, c++11

After playing Mancala with my brother, I thought coding the game would be a fun project to practice my abilities in C++. I am relatively new to programming, having only done a few small projects to experiment with the basic features of the language.  So I consider this to be my first legitimate application of my skills.

Although proud of my result I figured it could be better, especially since I have a function for each player (p1 and p2) instead of a player class.  The reason why is because I "translate" the inputs.  Hopefully that makes sense when looking at the code.  I tried to find other source code to compare to my game, but everything I have found so far does not make much use of C++ and is rather lengthy.  I appreciate any advice, but would really enjoy a full answer as to how to improve my code and further my abilities.

My code is separated into three parts; a menu class, a match class, and a main file.

**mancala.h**

```
#ifndef MANCALA_H
#define MANCALA_H

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

namespace mancala{  

    const std::vector<std::string> rules = {
        "\nOverview:\n\tMancala is an ancient family of board games,\n\tand there are numerous variants.\n\tThis is a version of the basic game,\n\tknown as two-rank Mancala and also known as Kalah.\n\t",
        "\nHoles & Stores:\n\tYour holes on the board are on the bottom right side.\n\tYour store is the last hole on your right.\n\t",
        "\nSow Stones:\n\tChoose a hole to pick up all pieces.\n\tMoving counter - clockwise, the game now deposits one of\n\tthe stones in each hole until the stones run out.\n\t",
        "\nStore:\n\tIf you run into your own store deposit one piece in it.\n\tIf you run into your opponents store, skip it.\n\t",
        "\nFree Turn:\n\tIf the last piece you drop is in your own store,\n\tyou get a free turn.\n\t",
        "\nCapture:\n\tIf the last piece you drop is on your side,\n\tyou capture that piece and any pieces in the\n\thole directly opposite.\n\t",
        "\nEnd:\n\tThe game ends when all six spaces on one side of the mancala\n\tboard are empty.  The player who still has pieces on his side of\n\tthe board when the game ends captures all of those pieces.\n\t",
        "\nWin:\n\tCount all the piecies in each store.\n\tThe winner is the player with the most pieces.\n\t"
    };    

    enum option{
        play = 1,
        info,
        quit 
    };

    class match{
        public://constructor
            match() : board{4,4,4,4,4,4,0,4,4,4,4,4,4,0}{
                begin();
                while(ingame)
                    {match::update();}
                results();
            };
        private://functions
            void results();
            void update();
            void begin();
            void end();
        //make player class
            void p1_display(const std::string& mod = "");
            void p2_display(const std::string& mod = "");
            int  p1_pit_select();
            int  p2_pit_select();
            bool p1_pit_distribute(const int& pit);
            bool p2_pit_distribute(const int& pit);
            bool p1_is_greater();
            bool p2_is_greater();
            bool p1_clear_pits();
            bool p2_clear_pits();

        private://variables
            static const int pits = 14;
            int board[pits];
            bool ingame;
    };
};

#endif//MANCALA_H
```

**mancala.cpp**

```
#include "mancala.h"

#include <unistd.h>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace mancala;

void match::update(){

    match::p1_display();

    switch(match::p1_clear_pits() || match::p2_is_greater() || match::p1_pit_distribute(match::p1_pit_select()) || match::p1_clear_pits() || match::p2_is_greater()){
        case true:
            end();
            return;
    }
    switch(match::p2_clear_pits() || match::p1_is_greater() || match::p2_pit_distribute(match::p2_pit_select()) || match::p2_clear_pits() || match::p1_is_greater()){
        case true:
            end();
            return;
    }
};

void match::begin(){
    ingame = true;
};

void match::end(){
    ingame = false;
};

void match::results(){
    if(board[13] < board[6]){
        std::cout << "    *** P1 Wins ***\n";
    }else if(board[13] > board[6]){
        std::cout << "    *** P2 Wins ***\n";
    }else if(board[13] == board[6]){
        std::cout << "    ***   Tie   ***\n";
    }else{
        std::cout << "    *** WHOOPS! ***\n";                   
    }sleep(2);
};

 int match::p1_pit_select(){
    std::cout << "Player 1: Enter(0-5): ";
    std::string s_input;
    int n_input;
    std::cin >> s_input;
    switch(s_input.at(0)){
        case '0': case '1': case '2':
        case '3': case '4': case '5':
            std::cin.putback(s_input.at(0));
            std::cin >> n_input;
            if(board[n_input] == 0){
                match::p1_display();
                return p1_pit_select();
            }return n_input;
        default:
            if(s_input == "back"){
                match::p1_display();
                return -1;
            }else{
                match::p1_display();
                return p1_pit_select();
            }
    } 
};

int trans(const unsigned int& index){
    return (7 + index) % 14;
};

int match::p2_pit_select(){
    std::cout << "Player 2: Enter(0-5): ";
    std::string s_input;
    int n_input;
    std::cin >> s_input;
    switch(s_input.at(0)){
        case '0': case '1': case '2':
        case '3': case '4': case '5':
            std::cin.putback(s_input.at(0));
            std::cin >> n_input;
            if(board[trans(n_input)] == 0){
                match::p2_display();
                return p2_pit_select();
            }return n_input;
        default:
            if(s_input == "back"){
                match::p2_display();
                return -1;
            }else{
                match::p2_display();
                return p2_pit_select();
            }
    } 
};

bool match::p2_clear_pits(){
    for(int index = 0; index < 6; index++){
        if(board[index] != 0) return false;
    }
    for(int index = 7; index < 13; index++){
        board[13] += board[index];
        board[index] = 0;
        match::p1_display();
    }return true;
};

bool match::p1_pit_distribute(const int& pit){//0-5
    if(pit == -1) return true;
    int markers = board[pit];
    board[pit] = 0;
    for(int index = 1; index <= markers; index++){
        if(index == markers){
        //*** last marker ***
            if(board[(pit + index) % 13] == 0 && (pit + index) != 6 && (pit + index) >= 0 && (pit + index) <= 5 && board[(12 - (pit + index))] != 0){
            //*** capture ***
                board[6] += board[12 - (index + pit)] + 1;
                board[12 - (index + pit)] = 0;
                match::p2_display();
            }else if((pit + index == 6) && !match::p2_clear_pits()){
                  //*** free turn ***
                board[6]+=1;    
                match::p1_display("P1: ⟲");
                p1_pit_distribute(match::p1_pit_select());
            }else{
             //*** deposit & end turn ***
                board[(pit + index) % 13]+=1;
                match::p2_display();
            }
        }else{
         //*** deposit ***
            board[(pit + index) % 13]+=1;
        }   
    }return false;  
};

bool match::p1_clear_pits(){
    for(int index = 7; index < 13; index++){
        if(board[index] != 0) return false;
    }
    for(int index = 0; index < 6; index++){
        board[6] += board[index];
        board[index] = 0;
        match::p2_display();
    }return true;
};

bool match::p2_pit_distribute(const int& pit){//0-5
    if(pit == -1) return true;
    int markers = board[trans(pit)];
    board[trans(pit)] = 0;
    for(int index = 1; index <= markers; index++){
        if(index == markers){
            if(board[trans((pit + index))] == 0 && trans(pit + index) != 13 && (pit + index) >= 0 && (pit + index) <= 5 && board[trans(12 - (pit + index))] != 0){
                board[13] += board[trans(12 - (index + pit))] + 1;
                board[trans(12 - (index + pit))] = 0;
                match::p1_display();
            }else if((trans(pit + index) == 13) && !p1_clear_pits()){
                board[13]+=1;
                match::p2_display("P2: ⟲");
                p2_pit_distribute(match::p2_pit_select());
            }else{
                board[trans(pit + index)]+=1;
                match::p1_display();
            }
        }else{
            board[trans(pit + index)]+=1;
        }
    }return false;  
};

static bool ask = true;

bool match::p2_is_greater(){
    if((board[13] > 24) && ask){
        match::p1_display("\b\bP2: > 24");
        std::cout << "Player 1: Continue?: ";
        std::string option;
        std::cin >> option;
        if(option == "yes"){
            match::p1_display();
            return ask = false;
        }else if(option == "no"){
            match::p1_display();
            return true;
        }else{
            match::p1_display();
            return p2_is_greater();
        }
    }else return false;
};

static bool _ask = true;

bool match::p1_is_greater(){
    if((board[6] > 24) && _ask){
        match::p2_display("\b\bP1: > 24");
        std::cout << "Player 2: Continue?: ";
        std::string option;
        std::cin >> option;
        if(option == "yes"){
            match::p2_display();
            return _ask = false;
        }else if(option == "no"){
            match::p2_display();
            return true;
        }else{
            match::p2_display();
            return p1_is_greater();
        }
    }else return false;
};

void match::p1_display(const std::string& mod){
    system("clear");
        for(int index = pits - 1; index >= pits / 2; index--)
            std::cout << std::setw(2) << std::setfill(' ') << board[index] << ' ';
        std::cout << "P1\nP2 ";
    for(int index = 0; index < pits / 2; index++)
        std::cout << std::setw(2) << std::setfill(' ') << board[index] << ' ';
    std::cout << "\n         " << mod << "\n   ";
    for(int index = 0; index < 6; index ++)
        std::cout << std::setw(2) << std::setfill('*') << index << ' ';
    std::cout << '\n';
};

void match::p2_display(const std::string& mod){
    system("clear");
    for(int index = pits - 1; index >= pits / 2; index--)
        std::cout << std::setw(2) << std::setfill(' ') << board[trans(index)] << ' ';
    std::cout << "P2\nP1 ";
    for(int index = 0; index < pits / 2; index++)
        std::cout << std::setw(2) << std::setfill(' ') << board[trans(index)] << ' ';
    std::cout << "\n         " << mod << "\n   ";
    for(int index = 0; index < 6; index ++)
        std::cout << std::setw(2) << std::setfill('*') << index << ' ';
    std::cout << '\n';
};
```

**menu.h**

```
#ifndef MENU_H
#define MENU_H

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

class menu{
    public:
        menu(const std::string& title, const std::vector<std::string>& options)
            : title(title), options(options){;};
        void display();
        int get_input();
    private:
        std::string title;
        std::vector<std::string> options;
};

#endif//MENU_H
```

**menu.cpp**

```
#include "menu.h"

#include <cstdlib>

int menu::get_input(){
    display();
    int index;
    std::cin >> index;
    if(!std::cin){
        std::cin.clear();
        std::cin.ignore(256, '\n');
        return get_input();
    }return index;
};

void menu::display(){
    system("clear");
    std::cout << title << std::endl;
    for(int index = 0; index < options.size(); index++){
        std::cout << "[" << index + 1 << "]" << options[index] << std::endl;
    }std::cout << "Enter index: ";
};
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include "mancala.h"
#include "menu.h"

menu home("Mancala - Type \"back\" from anywhere to return to the main menu. ", {"Play","Info","Quit"});

int main(){bool end = false;
    while(!end){
        switch(home.get_input()){
            case mancala::option::play:
                mancala::match();
                break;
            case mancala::option::info:
                system("clear");
                for(int index = 0; index < mancala::rules.size(); index++){
                    std::cout << "Mancala: Rules \n"            
                                 << mancala::rules[index] 
                                 << "   Enter any key: ";
                    std::string ws;
                    std::cin >> ws;
                    if(ws == "back"){
                        break;
                    }else{
                        system("clear");
                    }
                }
                break;
            case mancala::option::quit:
                end = true;
        }
    }return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please comment if the code is unclear.  I will be happy to add more comments to the code to make it more readable.  I realize its a little cryptic with the magic numbers.

Comment: I would really like if someone were to try out the game.  I am using a system command defined in <cstdlib> to clear the screen and a sleep command defined in <unistd.h>, but they are not needed to run the program.

Comment: For clarity, you realize this isn't even remotely Objective-C, right?

Comment: Sorry if I miss used the term.  So Objective-C and C++ are not the same?

Comment: Not even remotely.

Comment: Should I make a player class inside the match class or just within the mancala namespace?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have found a couple of things that could help you improve your code.

### Avoid the use of global variables

I see that `home` is declared as global variable, but there's no reason it can't instead be a variable within `main`. It's generally better to keep the scope of variables as small as practical.

### Fix the formatting

This line is badly formatted:

```
int main(){bool end = false;
```

Running things together like that makes your code hard to read and understand.  I'd format it like this instead:

```
int main()
{
    bool end = false;
    // etc.
```

### Don't use `system("clear")`

There are two reasons not to use `system("clear")`. The first is that it is not portable to other operating systems which you may or may not care about now.  The second is that it's a security hole, which you absolutely **must** care about.  Specifically, if some program is defined and named `clear`, your program will execute that program instead of what you intend, and that other program could be anything.  First, isolate this into a separate functions `cls()` and then modify your code to call those functions instead of `system`.  Then rewrite the contents of those functions to do what you want using C++. An example using ANSI escape sequences:

```
void cls()
{
    std::cout << "\x1b[2J";
}
```

### Eliminate spurious semicolons

There are a lot of spurious semicolons at the end of function definitions.  For example:

```
int trans(const unsigned int& index){
        return (7 + index) % 14;
};  // <-- this semicolon is neither needed nor welcome!
```

Eliminating those will make your code a bit easier to read and understand.

### Use a player object

As you've already noted, your code would benefit greatly from having a `player` object.  If we look at `p1_display` and `p2_display` for example, only a single line is different in the most trivial way.  This could easily be made into a member function of a `player` object.

### Use `const` where practical

Several of your member functions, such as `results()` do not alter the underlying object.  For that reason, those functions should be declared `const` like this:

```
void match::results() const { // etc.
```

### Avoid strange constructions

Normally, a `switch` statement has multiple `case`s.  However this code contains this odd bit of code:

```
switch(match::p2_clear_pits() || match::p1_is_greater() || match::p2_pit_distribute(match::p2_pit_select()) || match::p2_clear_pits() || match::p1_is_greater()){
    case true:
        end();
        return;
}
```

First, it's odd because it only has a single case.  It could be an `if` statement instead.  Second, it's hard to read because the line is so long.  If we pull it apart, we get to the next strange part:

```
if (match::p1_clear_pits() || match::p2_is_greater() || 
        match::p1_pit_distribute(match::p1_pit_select()) || 
        match::p1_clear_pits() || match::p2_is_greater()) {  //etc.
```

The first and third lines are identical.  Unfortunately, the `p1_pit_distribute` actually alters the state, so we can't simply eliminate the third line.  This *really* needs to be refactored.  I'd suggest a simple `hasWon()` function to determine if one or the other has won, and not to abuse short-circuit evaluation this way.

### Separate I/O from program logic

Right now most individual functions have both game logic and I/O.  It's often better design to separate the two so that the game logic is independent of the I/O with the user.  That way if you decided, for instance, to make a GUI version, only the I/O parts would need to be touched.  It also makes your code easier to understand and to fix, even if you never change the I/O.

### Don't abuse an object constructor

The constructor for `match` looks like this:

```
match() : board{4,4,4,4,4,4,0,4,4,4,4,4,4,0}{
    begin();
    while(ingame)
        {match::update();}
    results();
};
```

This is not good design.  Instead, separate the two concepts of construction and playing.  It might look like this:

```
match() : board{4,4,4,4,4,4,0,4,4,4,4,4,4,0}
{}
void play() {
    while (update()) 
    { }
    results();
}
```

Note that `ingame` is eliminated entirely, and that `update` now returns `true` until the game is complete.  This also, of course, completely eliminates the need for `begin()` and `end()` member functions as well.

### Think of the user

The instructions are printed only two or three lines at a time.  Unless your display is only expected to be three lines high, this makes it much more work for the user to read and understand the instructions as a while.  For that reason, I'd recommend simply having the whole of the instructions as a single string rather than a vector of strings.

Comment: How do you suggest I separate the io from programming logic.  Should I let main handle io and make functions in the player class to read these input values from main?

Comment: Yes, that's how I'd approach it.  Alternatively, if that proves unwieldy, you could add separate and isolated helper functions that only do I/O.  Could even be implemented as another class, as in [the MVC pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller).

Comment: s/practical/possible.  A variable's scope should be as small as possible.  A variable's scope should never be any larger than necessary.

Comment: @nhgrif: I'm not so sure.  Consider searching an array with a loop counter in a `for` loop.  The loop counter variable *could* be made valid only within the loop, but it may be handy to remember which item matched the search criterion, in which case the loop variable's scope could well be larger than *possible*, but add convenience to the programmer.

Answer (score 3):

One thing that's easy to change and would make your code more readable would be to change the rules function from a vector to just a void function that prints the rules itself and would look like:

```
void print_rules = {
    std::cout << "\nOverview:\n\tMancala is an ancient family of board games,\n\tand there are numerous variants.\n\tThis is a version of the basic game,\n\tknown as two-rank Mancala and also known as Kalah.\n\t";
    std::cout << "\nHoles & Stores:\n\tYour holes on the board are on the bottom right side.\n\tYour store is the last hole on your right.\n\t";
    std::cout << "\nSow Stones:\n\tChoose a hole to pick up all pieces.\n\tMoving counter - clockwise, the game now deposits one of\n\tthe stones in each hole until the stones run out.\n\t";
    std::cout << "\nStore:\n\tIf you run into your own store deposit one piece in it.\n\tIf you run into your opponents store, skip it.\n\t";
    std::cout << "\nFree Turn:\n\tIf the last piece you drop is in your own store,\n\tyou get a free turn.\n\t";
    std::cout << "\nCapture:\n\tIf the last piece you drop is on your side,\n\tyou capture that piece and any pieces in the\n\thole directly opposite.\n\t";
    std::cout << "\nEnd:\n\tThe game ends when all six spaces on one side of the mancala\n\tboard are empty.  The player who still has pieces on his side of\n\tthe board when the game ends captures all of those pieces.\n\t";
    std::cout << "\nWin:\n\tCount all the piecies in each store.\n\tThe winner is the player with the most pieces.\n\t";
}
```

This eliminates the need for the for-loop in the main function. Unless there was a reason you only wanted to print one rule at a time and then ask for user input but that's probably not great design anyway. If a user just wants to know how the game ends, they have to input a random key 6 times to get there. Doing it this way will almost cut the code in the main function in half and doesn't even add extra code anywhere else.

Another thing, as @Edward said before, sometimes the use of switch statements seems  unnecessary. Another example is in the function `p1_pit_select` and `p2_pit_select` where you have

```
switch(s_input.at(0)){
    case '0': case '1': case '2':
    case '3': case '4': case '5':
        std::cin.putback(s_input.at(0));
        std::cin >> n_input;
        if(board[trans(n_input)] == 0){
            match::p2_display();
            return p2_pit_select();
        }return n_input;
    default:
        if(s_input == "back"){
            match::p2_display();
            return -1;
        }else{
            match::p2_display();
            return p2_pit_select();
        }
}
```

Which would be much simpler and easier understood if you used an if instead of a switch statement. The shortest one I can think of would be

```
if ((s_input.at(0) < 0) || (s_input.at(0) > 5))
```

And the default would just be in an `else`.